# Extract HttpServletResponse body to string

Tags: java, servlets

Is there any way to extract HttpServletResponse's body to string?

I cannot use filters since the request never actually gets sent back via HTTP but needs to be converted into a different model (legacy project where HttpServletResponse was treated as a data container everywhere and things are changing now).

Comment: Call `getOutputStream` and read it into a `String` with `org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString` perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

think you can do something like this extend HttpServletResponseWrapper (more detail here https://www.gnu.org/software/classpathx/servletapi/javadoc/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponseWrapper.html)

```
 public class ResponseWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {
    private final CharArrayWriter writer = new CharArrayWriter();

    public ResponseWrapper(HttpServletResponse response) {
        super(response);
    }

    @Override
    public PrintWriter getWriter() {
        return new PrintWriter(writer);
    }

    public String getResponseBody() {
        return writer.toString();
    }
}
```

so you can ovverride the writer for the HttpServletResponse then create another function to get the string.

then use it like this

```
   ResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new ResponseWrapper(resp);
 
   String responseBody = responseWrapper.getResponseBody();
```